# RDS console showing monthly estimated charges for Free Tier Limit in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Why is RDS console on Amazon Web Services showing an estimated monthly charge if I start creating a RDS instance. I am using a free tier account and is well within free tier limit.

This is what my console is showing:

[image: console]

This is within the free tier limits, which I found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/).

Why does this happen, and will it actually charge me anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Amazon RDS console has no visibility into any other services you have (or will) consume during the month. It is simply showing an estimate of the costs for running the database.

The benefits of the [free usage tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) will be calculated separately, based upon actual usage.

So, if that's the only RDS instance you run during the month and it qualifies for the free tier, you will not be charged.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Postgres database on the AWS RDS free tier.
Everything was set up using the free tier:
Amazon RDS Single-AZ  db.t3.micro ([details about my setting here](https://yuriyni.com/postgresql/public-postgres-on-aws-rds/))

And at the end of page, I`ve got this info below:

Estimated Monthly costs
DB instance 13.14 USD
Storage 2.30 USD
Total 15.44 USD

Hope next month I will not be charged. Will reply about it soon...

Comment: So, were you charged?

Comment: I would also like to know this? :)

Comment: I have got a "Cost and usage breakdown" from AWS Console "Billing and Cost Management" > "Cost Analysis" > "Cost Explorer" section (for details and screenshot click the link above)

Relational Database Service (TOTAL $36.45 ), 
September 2023 $5.50,  
October 2023 $15.69,
November 2023 $15.26